# ServeRaid M5210 high temperature

Tags: raid, ssd, raid10

I have a serveraid M5210 card on X3650 m5 (raid10)
And a M5110e raid card  on X3650 m4

Both raid card is high temperature (70-75 C)

images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A4L8.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5maa.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXjMN.jpg

Is this temperature normally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most silicon will work flawlessly up to ~ 90/95° C, however, you should really check the RAID card manual and specifications to be sure.

Being passively cooled, RoC's relatively high temperature (75° C) does not surprise me. Please be sure that case ventilation and room temperature are adequate.

Comment: room temperature is 27°C. raid card is passively cooled. The raid card location is this pic:
[http://imgur.com/MHtwsGn](http://imgur.com/MHtwsGn)

Comment: From [here](https://lenovopress.com/tips1069-serveraid-m5210-sas-sata-controller#operating-environment), you can see that your RAID card is should work with room temperature as high as to 40°C. So it seems all is OK in your setup.